# How to assign value to directive using javascript code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I am doing validation for textbox. I am doing range validation. textbox should accept numbers within the specified range. I have developed directive for this purpose. I am assigning value as range-number="10,4096". Instead of assigning value in this tag i want to assign in angularjs code.

Below is my html.

```
  <div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form5.$submitted && form5.DownPayment.$invalid )|| (form5.DownPayment.$invalid && form5.DownPayment.$dirty))}">
                        <div>
                            <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form5.DownPayment.$dirty && form5.DownPayment.$invalid  && form5.DownPayment.$error.rangeNumber">
                                <span ng-show="form5.DownPayment.$invalid && form5.DownPayment.$dirty">Invalid</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="" type="text" name="DownPayment" placeholder="{{ 'DownPayment' | translate }}" ng-model="DownPayment" required ng-readonly="makereadonlyDownPayment" range-number="range">
                    </div>
```

Below is my js code.

```
app.directive('rangeNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            var range = attrs.rangeNumber.split(',').map(Number);
            ctrl.$validators.rangeNumber = function (value) {
                return value >= range[0] && value <= range[1];
            };
        }
    };
});
```

May i know how can i do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You know AngularJS has a directive already written for this? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Brange%5D In there you can set $scope.max and $scope.min

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array with these informations to your directive, your html can be like:

`<input class="" type="text" name="DownPayment" placeholder="{{ 'DownPayment' | translate }}" ng-model="DownPayment" required ng-readonly="makereadonlyDownPayment" range-number="range">`

and you retrieve the variable range with an isolate scope into your directive:

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        range: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;
        var range = scope.range;
        ctrl.$validators.rangeNumber = function (value) {
            return value >= range[0] && value <= range[1];
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So i should create array in my controller?

Comment: yes, create a range variable in your controller $scope (or vm object)

Comment: I have created   $scope.range = ['10','100']; and not working.

Comment: i tried as   $scope.range[0] = '10';
                $scope.range[1] = '20'; and this is also not working. May i know something i am missing? Thank you

Comment: I'll test a solution and I give you more informations soon

Comment: you can pass an int array to your directive: `[10, 100]` because your variable is evaluate by the directive ('=' flag), be sure to access the variable to your $validators callback. you have to init the range variable into an external controller, not in the directive controller.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve your problem

```
app.directive('rangeNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;
            var range = scope.$eval(attrs.rangeNumber);
            range = range.split(',').map(Number);


            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
              value = +value;
              var isValidRange = !(value >= range[0] && value <= range[1]);
              ctrl.$setValidity('range', isValidRange);

              return value;
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.range = '1,4096';
// or you can make it array, but in that case you have to remove split 
//and map functions from the directive
$scope.range = [1, 4096];
```

HTML

```
<input class="" type="text" name="rangeNumber" ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'DownPayment' }}" ng-model="DownPayment"  range-number="range">
<p ng-show="!sampleForm.rangeNumber.$invalid && sampleForm.rangeNumber.$dirty">Number not in range</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yordan_nikolov/pwejm6de/

Edited

Comment: Thank you for helping. I want to assign values in controller.

Comment: you mean that you want to replace the hardcoded range `1,4096` with range from the controller, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148594/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-yordan-nikolov).